# Run command shell script [cp] embed pods framework' 0.2 seconds Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, error-handling, cocoapods

I update my Mac with mojave and install Xcode 10 but found error :-

```
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code


Showing Recent Messages
PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/developernaveen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/idea-factory-dmfuztlahigkdhbilbebrzgshtns/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/idea-factory/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/idea-factory.build/Release-iphoneos/idea-factory.build/Script-C20DE6E02C27C057DF7F6A85.sh (in target: idea-factory)
    cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my/mindwalk/apps/idea-factory
    /bin/sh -c /Users/developernaveen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/idea-factory-dmfuztlahigkdhbilbebrzgshtns/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/idea-factory/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/idea-factory.build/Release-iphoneos/idea-factory.build/Script-C20DE6E02C27C057DF7F6A85.sh

mkdir -p /Users/developernaveen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/idea-factory-dmfuztlahigkdhbilbebrzgshtns/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/idea-factory/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/idea-factory.app/Frameworks
Symlinked...
rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "/Users/developernaveen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/idea-factory-dmfuztlahigkdhbilbebrzgshtns/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/idea-factory/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Alamofire.framework" "/Users/developernaveen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/idea-factory-dmfuztlahigkdhbilbebrzgshtns/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/idea-factory/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/idea-factory.app/Frameworks"
building file list ... done
Alamofire.framework/
Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
Alamofire.framework/Info.plist

sent 7388962 bytes  received 70 bytes  14778064.00 bytes/sec
total size is 7387818  speedup is 1.00
Code Signing /Users/developernaveen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/idea-factory-dmfuztlahigkdhbilbebrzgshtns/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/idea-factory/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/idea-factory.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework with Identity iPhone Distribution: Aneesh Seth (JNS8JV6ZP8)
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 7299CBC3A21D2A8299B8E7EC03041273C3B558E2  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/developernaveen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/idea-factory-dmfuztlahigkdhbilbebrzgshtns/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/idea-factory/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/idea-factory.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework'
/Users/developernaveen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/idea-factory-dmfuztlahigkdhbilbebrzgshtns/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/idea-factory/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/idea-factory.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework: errSecInternalComponent
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I do all thing with my hand like :-
1. clean project
2. keychain lock n unlock
3. restart Mac
4. pod update / install

Now I don't know what to do...!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Comment: this issue when I transfer this project one mac to another latest mac os. but still I can't find